# How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I turn a list of dicts like `[{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':2}]`, into a single dict like `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':2}`?

---

<sub>Answers here will *overwrite* keys that match between two of the input dicts, because a dict cannot have duplicate keys. If you want to *collect* multiple values from matching keys, see [How to merge dicts, collecting values from matching keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-dicts-collecting-values-from-matching-keys).</sub>

Comment: There really should be a one liner for this considering how often it comes up. Is there a reason why {**d for d in d_list} isn't supported?

Comment: @markemus being able to use star-unpacking in the first clause of a comprehension would quickly lead to chaos. For just one example: should `[*a for a in (range(i) for i in range(10))]` flatten the output or not? A feature like this would take a LOT of careful design work. Also, for dict comprehensions specifically, the `:` is kind of needed in the syntax, or else how do you know it isn't a set comprehension instead?

Comment: @markemus See [Unpacking generalizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41251729/674039) about that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm not convinced on those syntactical points. The first example _should_ flatten the output, because not flattening it would be written as just `[range(i) for i in range(10)]`. A set union/unpack would look like `{*s for s in ss}` and dict merge/unpack would look like `{**d for d in ds}`. So, the * vs ** is enough - no `:` is needed.

Comment: " The first example should flatten the output," Okay, now have fun writing the parser logic for that, and making it not go "well, each `*a` produces a list clearly, and then we have a list comprehension of those".

Answer (score 305, accepted):

This works for dictionaries of any length:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for d in L:
...    result.update(d)
... 
>>> result
{'a':1,'c':1,'b':2,'d':2}
```

As a [comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
# Python >= 2.7
{k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}

# Python < 2.7
dict(pair for d in L for pair in d.items())
```

Answer (score 183):

In case of Python 3.3+, there is a [`ChainMap` collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> a = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':1},{'d':2}]
>>> dict(ChainMap(*a))
{'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'a': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Also see:

- [What is the purpose of collections.ChainMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392976/what-is-the-purpose-of-collections-chainmap)

Comment: slower by 10fold from 1st dict comprehension solution

Answer (score 28):

Little improvement for [@dietbuddha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247357/dietbuddha) answer with dictionary unpacking from [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), for me, it`s more readable this way, also, it is [faster as well](https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/f35292e676efa0be1728):

```
from functools import reduce
result_dict = reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, list_of_dicts)
```

But keep in mind, this works only with Python 3.5+ versions.

Comment: After Python 3.9, the dictionary supports the use of `|` operator, so we can use `reduce(operator.ior, list_of_dicts, {})` instead, which will get the best performance.

Comment: This `operator.ior` version works very nicely.

Comment: Though I would use `operator.or_`, since `ior` is in-place, thus silently modifying the first dictionary in the list.

Answer (score 16):

This is similar to @delnan but offers the option to modify the k/v (key/value) items and I believe is more readable:

```
new_dict = {k:v for list_item in list_of_dicts for (k,v) in list_item.items()}
```

for instance, replace k/v elems as follows:

```
new_dict = {str(k).replace(" ","_"):v for list_item in list_of_dicts for (k,v) in list_item.items()}
```

unpacks the k,v tuple from the dictionary .items() generator after pulling the dict object out of the list

Answer (score 12):

For flat dictionaries you can do this:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), list_of_dicts)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [join](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/colls.html#join) function from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import join
join(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: I think it's an underrated answer...

Comment: Use this and not mine.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> L=[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 1}, {'d': 2}]    
>>> dict(i.items()[0] for i in L)
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2}
```

Note: the order of 'b' and 'c' doesn't match your output because dicts are unordered

if the dicts can have more than one key/value

```
>>> dict(j for i in L for j in i.items())
```

Comment: Fails if any of the dicts in the list has more than one item.

Comment: *cough*(assuming each dictionary contains only one key-value pair)*cough*

Comment: Ah, well first I posted a method that works with general dicts, but it looked like the OP didn't need that

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the singleton dicts anymore:

```
>>> L = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':2}]
>>> dict(map(dict.popitem, L))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: This is really weird and breaks _silently_ if any of the dicts has more than one item.

Comment: Breaks for me too, eg: with `L = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':2, 'e':3}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
dict1.update( dict2 )
```

This is asymmetrical because you need to choose what to do with duplicate keys; in this case, `dict2` will overwrite `dict1`. Exchange them for the other way.

EDIT: Ah, sorry, didn't see that.

It is possible to do this in a single expression:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict( chain( *map( dict.items, theDicts ) ) )
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 2}
```

No credit to me for this last!

However, I'd argue that it might be more Pythonic (explicit > implicit, flat > nested ) to do this with a simple `for` loop. YMMV.

Comment: its a list and not a dict:
>>> type([{'a':1},{'b':2}])  <type 'list'>

Answer (score 2):

This way worked for me:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':1, 'd':2}]
merged_dict = {k: v for dct in list_of_dicts for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Printing `merged_dict`:

```
{'a':1,'b':2,'c':1,'d':2}
```

thanks [Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12479639/axe319)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and `|` seems to be slightly faster than the list comprehension in the accepted answer.

```
In [1]: %timeit reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1 | d2, L)
428 ns ± 5.41 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit {k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}
476 ns ± 15.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [3]: reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1 | d2, L) == {k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dictlist = [{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':1},{'d':2, 'e':3}]
>>> dict(kv for d in dictlist for kv in d.iteritems())
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 3, 'd': 2}
>>>
```

Note I added a second key/value pair to the last dictionary to show it works with multiple entries.
Also keys from dicts later in the list will overwrite the same key from an earlier dict.