# How to merge dicts from a list of dicts in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have racked my brain over this for a long time and now am handing it over to the wiser ones. I have a list of dicts (the length of the list can vary from 1 to 100s). These lists have mostly duplicates with one or two values varying. The keys for all the dict always remain the same. An example would be like below:

```
myList = [
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "v31", "k4" : "v41"},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v22", "k3" : "", "k4" : ""},
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "", "k4" : "v41"},
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "v31", "k4" : ""},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v22", "k3" : "v32", "k4" : ""}
]
```

Now I know that myList[0], myList[2] and myList[3] are same, as majority of their present values are same. Similarly, myList[1] and myList[4] are the same.

What I want is to implement a function merge(myList) which will give an output like this:

```
newList = [
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "v31", "k4" : "v41"},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v22", "k3" : "v32", "k4" : ""}
]
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Cheers,
Paritosh

Comment: So why is `"k3": ""` being ignored? What are the rules for merging, *exactly*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Comment: Rules for merging are: if two dicts have the maximum no of duplicate values (for corresponding keys), merge them. And its not a possible duplicate of the mentioned question because I don't want to merge all the dicts into a single dict, the dicts with the maximum possible common values should merge. If all the dicts have different values, they should not merge.

Comment: This is why you need to state such requirements **up front**. Your merging rules are still unclear; how are dictionaries selected for merging? Adjacency, or are you pairing up all dictionaries with all other dictionaries? What does 'maximum no of duplicate values' **mean**, you want to merge two dictionaries when they share the most values compared to all other dictionaries in your list? You do realize that if that is true you are going to have to make an exponential number of comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

I'd collect all values into `defaultdict` with `set` values, then unzip the values back into separate dictionaries; from some experimentation I am guessing you want to ignore empty values and only put them back in to make up the output dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip_longest

values = defaultdict(set)
for map in myList:
    for key, value in map.iteritems():
        if value:
            values[key].add(value)

keys = list(values)
newList = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in izip_longest(*(sorted(v) for v in values.itervalues()), fillvalue='')]
```

Now we get:

```
[{'k1': 'v11', 'k2': 'v21', 'k3': 'v31', 'k4': 'v41'},
 {'k1': 'v12', 'k2': 'v22', 'k3': 'v32', 'k4': ''}]
```

Comment: I checked the solution. It works beautifully for the given values. However, if we complicate the input slightly more, it fails. For e.g., `myList = [
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "v31", "k4" : "v41"},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v22", "k3" : "", "k4" : ""},
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "", "k4" : "v41"},
{"k1" : "v11", "k2" : "v21", "k3" : "v31", "k4" : ""},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v22", "k3" : "v32", "k4" : ""},
{"k1" : "v12", "k2" : "v23", "k3" : "v33", "k4" : "v43"}
]` . I expect an output with myList[5] as a separate dict, as max values aren't dupes.