# PYTHON 2.7 - Modifying List of Lists and Re-Assembling Without Mutating

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, iterator, nested-lists, listiterator

I currently have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
My_List = [[This, Is, A, Sample, Text, Sentence] [This, too, is, a, sample, text] [finally, so, is, this, one]]
```

Now what I need to do is "tag" each of these words with one of 3, in this case arbitrary, tags such as "EE", "FF", or "GG" based on which list the word is in and then reassemble them into the same order they came in. My final code would need to look like:

```
GG_List = [This, Sentence]
FF_List = [Is, A, Text]
EE_List = [Sample]

My_List = [[(This, GG), (Is, FF), (A, FF), (Sample, "EE), (Text, FF), (Sentence, GG)] [*same with this sentence*] [*and this one*]]
```

I tried this by using for loops to turn each item into a dict but the dicts then got rearranged by their tags which sadly can't happen because of the nature of this thing... the experiment needs **everything** to stay in the same order because eventually I need to measure the proximity of tags relative to others but only in the same sentence (list).

<s>I thought about doing this with NLTK (which I have little experience with) but it looks like that is much more sophisticated then what I need and the tags aren't easily customized by a novice like myself.</s>

I think this could be done by iterating through each of these items, using an if statement as I have to determine what tag they should have, and then making a tuple out of the word and its associated tag so it doesn't shift around within its list.

I've devised this.. but I can't figure out how to rebuild my list-of-lists and keep them in order :(.

```
for i in My_List: #For each list in the list of lists
    for h in i:   #For each item in each list
         if h in GG_List:  # Check for the tag
            MyDicts = {"GG":h for h in i}  #Make Dict from tag + word
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. You want to tag them "based on which list the word is in" but your output doesn't seem to follow that pattern?

Comment: @erewok hmm... take for example the first sentence: [This, Is, A, Sample, Text, Sentence]. Because the word "Sample" is found in the other list titled "GG_List", the word "Sample" becomes (Sample, GG). Does that clarify?

Comment: What is your desired output? Can you show an example? Also, i don't think this has anything to do with `nltk` ;P

Comment: Don't mind if I remove the `nltk` tag since it don't seem related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the tags in a dictionary would work:

```
My_List = [['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Sample', 'Text', 'Sentence'],
           ['This', 'too', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'text'],
           ['finally', 'so', 'is', 'this', 'one']]
GG_List = ['This', 'Sentence']
FF_List = ['Is', 'A', 'Text']
EE_List = ['Sample']

zipped = zip((GG_List, FF_List, EE_List), ('GG', 'FF', 'EE'))
tags = {item: tag for tag_list, tag in zipped for item in tag_list}
res = [[(word, tags[word]) for word in entry if word in tags] for entry in My_List]
```

Now:

```
>>> res
[[('This', 'GG'),
  ('Is', 'FF'),
  ('A', 'FF'),
  ('Sample', 'EE'),
  ('Text', 'FF'),
  ('Sentence', 'GG')],
 [('This', 'GG')],
 []]
```

Comment: The problem is Mike that this flattens out my list of lists. I have to keep the lists of list in tact for this to be a valid experiment. Any idea how I could deal with that?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary works by key-value pairs. Each key is assigned a value. To search the dictionary, you search the index by the key, e.g.

```
>>> d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
>>> d[1]
'a'
```

In the above case, we always search the dictionary by its keys, i.e. the integers.

In the case that you want to assign the tag/label to each word, you are searching by the key word and finding the "value", i.e. the tag/label, so your dictionary would have to look something like this (assuming that the strings are words and numbers as tag/label):

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':3}
>>> d['a']
1
>>> sent = 'a b c a b'.split()
>>> sent
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>> [d[word] for word in sent]
[1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
```

This way the order of the tags follows the order of the words when you use a list comprehension to iterate through the words and find the appropriate tags.

So the problem comes when you have the initial dictionary indexed with the wrong way, i.e. key -> labels, value -> words, e.g.:

```
>>> d = {1:['a', 'd'], 2:['b', 'h'], 3:['c', 'x']}
>>> [d[word] for word in sent]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
```

Then you would have to reverse your dictionary, assuming that all elements in your value lists are unique, you can do this:

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> d = {1:['a', 'd'], 2:['b', 'h'], 3:['c', 'x']}
>>> d_inv = dict(ChainMap(*[{value:key for value in values} for key, values in d.items()]))
>>> d_inv
{'h': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'x': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
```

But the caveat is that `ChainMap` is only available in Python3.5 (yet another reason to upgrade your Python ;P). For Python <3.5, solutions, see [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict).

So going back to the problem of assigning labels/tags to words, let's say we have these input:

```
>>> d = {1:['a', 'd'], 2:['b', 'h'], 3:['c', 'x']}
>>> sent = 'a b c a b'.split()
```

First, we invert the dictionary (assuming that there're one to one mapping for every word and its tag/label:

```
>>> d_inv = dict(ChainMap(*[{value:key for value in values} for key, values in d.items()]))
```

Then, we apply the tags to the words through a list comprehension:

```
>>> [d_inv[word] for word in sent]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

And for multiple sentences:

```
>>> sentences = ['a b c'.split(), 'h a x'.split()]
>>> [[d_inv[word] for word in sent] for sent in sentences]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Shameless plug: we wrote a brief intro to lists and python containers for a basic python tutorial and that might help you better understand how to use them for NLP. Take a look at " Comprehending Containers" session in https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups

Comment: Thanks for your input man! I wasn't clear enough with what output I was looking for and Mike's solution got my closer to what I needed based on what I had. Thank you so much for all of your explanations and examples though - they helped explain a lot to me!!

Comment: No problem, i'm glad the answer helped.