# Unpacking generalizations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-3.5, iterable-unpacking

[PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) allowed:

```
>>> LOL = [[1, 2], ['three']]
>>> [*LOL[0], *LOL[1]]
[1, 2, 'three']
```

Alright!  Goodbye [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).  Never liked you much anyway.

```
>>> [*L for L in LOL]
  File "<ipython-input-21-e86d2c09c33f>", line 1
    [*L for L in LOL]
    ^
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

**Oh**.  Why can't we have nice things?

Unfortunately there are syntax errors for all of them:

```
[*l for l in lists]    # for l in lists: result.extend(l)
{*s for s in sets}     # for s in sets: result.update(s)
{**d for d in dicts}   # for d in dicts: result.update(d)
(*g for g in gens)     # for g in gens: yield from g
```

Unpacking in a comprehension seems to be obvious and Pythonic, and there's a quite natural extension from shorthand "for-loop & append" to "for-loop & extend".

But since they've bothered to add that special error message, there was presumably a reason for disabling it. So, what's the problem with that syntax?

Comment: you add a a second loop: `[item for L in LOL for item in L]` Possibly to remove ambiguity as to which one should be used.

Comment: This hasn't been ruled out for the future (the initial implementation *had* it from what I know), looking for the reference on this.

Comment: See the acceptance message [on py-dev, there's a paragraph on comps.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-February/138564.html)

Comment: P.s your naming conventions are *horrible*!

Comment: @wim `[item for L in LOL for item in L[:3]]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is *briefly* explained in the [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#variations) which introduces unpacking generalizations:

> Earlier iterations of this PEP allowed unpacking operators inside
> list, set, and dictionary comprehensions as a flattening operator over
> iterables of containers:
>
> ```
> >>> ranges = [range(i) for i in range(5)]
> >>> [*item for item in ranges]
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>
> >>> {*item for item in ranges}
> {0, 1, 2, 3}
> ```
>
> This was met with a mix of strong concerns about readability and mild
> support. In order not to disadvantage the less controversial aspects
> of the PEP, this was not accepted with the rest of the proposal.

However, this may change in the future:

> This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although this has not been ruled out for future proposals.

---

The PEP mentions "strong concerns about readability". I don't know the entire story, but the detailed discussions that led to this decision can certainly be found in the mailing list:

- [[Python-ideas] PEP for issue2292, "Missing *-unpacking generalizations"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-July/021872.html)
- [[Python-ideas] What's going on with PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations ?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-January/031012.html)

Here is an ambiguous example if unpacking generalizations were to be allowed in list comprehension:

```py
[*t for t in [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]]
```

[According to one of the core developers](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-October/042816.html), it would be surprising for the result to be `[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c']` and not `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`.

Since there was no formal consensus, it was simpler not to allow these special cases.

Comment: I see that in the PEP, but what were the "strong concerns about readability"? Could you summarize them in your answer?

Comment: @wim I don't really know the details but I tried to add an example.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! Steven D'Aprano's message is bizarre - the unpacking generalization to *for-loop + extend* is obvious and natural. It's hard to understand how a core developer could consider it "*very strange*" and "*never in a million years*" expect that result.

Answer (score 27):

Taking a quote from [the Py-Dev mailing list thread in which this feature was accepted](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-February/138564.html):

> So that leaves comprehensions. IIRC, during the development of the patch we realized that `f(*x for x in xs)` is ***sufficiently ambiguous*** that we decided to disallow it -- note that `f(x for x in xs)` is already somewhat of a special case because an argument can only be a "bare" generator expression if it is the only argument. The same reasoning doesn't apply (in that form) to list, set and dict comprehensions -- while `f(x for x in xs)` is identical in meaning to `f((x for x in xs))`, `[x for x in xs]` is NOT the same as `[(x for x in xs)]` (that's a list of one element, and the element is a generator
>   expression)

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

I also took a peek at the Python issue tracker for this feature. I found an issue in which discussion took place while implementing it. The sequence of messages that helped them come to this realization starts [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue2292#msg234754) with a nice overview of the ambiguity introduced presented in [msg234766](http://bugs.python.org/issue2292#msg234766) by GvR.

In *fear* of link-rot, I'm attaching the (formatted) message here:

> So I think the test function here should be:
>
> ```
> def f(*a, **k): print(list(a), list(k))
> ```
>
> Then we can try things like:
>
> ```
> f(x for x in ['ab', 'cd'])
> ```
>
> which prints a generator object, because this is interpreted as an argument that's a generator expression.
>
> But now let's consider:
>
> ```
> f(*x for x in ['ab', 'cd'])
> ```
>
> I personally expected this to be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> f(*'ab', *'cd')
> ```
>
> IOW:
>
> ```
>  f('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
> ```
>
> *The PEP doesn't give clarity on what to do here.  The question now is, should we interpret things like `*x for x in ...` as an extended form of generator expression, or as an extended form of `*arg`?  I somehow think the latter is more useful and also the more logical extension.*
>
> My reasoning is that the PEP supports things like `f(*a, *b)` and it would be fairly logical to interpret `f(*x for x in xs)` as doing the `*x` thing for each `x` in the list `xs`.

Finally, as noted in [the Abstract section of the corresponding PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#abstract), this feature isn't completely ruled out:

> This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although *this has not been ruled out for future proposals*.

So, we might get to see it sometime soon (definitely not 3.6, though :-) and I hope we do, they look nice.

Comment: I think it's only an argument against implementing the unpacking *function call* syntax. Why couldn't it be that `[*x for x in xs]`, which is not at all ambiguous, is supported and `f(*x for x in xs)` remains a syntax error?