# How do I merge array of list of dicts into a single dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have input data like below

```
[{'s1': 'INT', 's2': 'INT'}, {'s1': 'TINYINT', 's2': 'TINYINT'}, {'s1': 'SMALLINT', 's2': 'SMALLINT'}, {'s1': 'BIGINT', 's2': 'BIGINT'}, {'s1': 'BIT', 's2': 'VARCHAR(10)'}, {'s1': 'FLOAT', 's2': 'FLOAT'}]
```

and want output as below.

```
{'INT':'INT', 'TINYINT': 'TINYINT', 'SMALLINT': 'SMALLINT', 'BIGINT': 'BIGINT', 'BIT': 'VARCHAR(10)', 'FLOAT': 'FLOAT'}
```

I have gone through the below SO question but didn't have no luck.

[How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach.

```
s = [{'s1': 'INT', 's2': 'INT'}, {'s1': 'TINYINT', 's2': 'TINYINT'}, {'s1': 'SMALLINT', 's2': 'SMALLINT'}, {'s1': 'BIGINT', 's2': 'BIGINT'}, {'s1': 'BIT', 's2': 'VARCHAR(10)'}, {'s1': 'FLOAT', 's2': 'FLOAT'}]
print(dict((i["s1"], i["s2"]) for i in s))
```

**Output:**

```
{'SMALLINT': 'SMALLINT', 'INT': 'INT', 'FLOAT': 'FLOAT', 'TINYINT': 'TINYINT', 'BIGINT': 'BIGINT', 'BIT': 'VARCHAR(10)'}
```

Comment: this solution will also work for python versions <2.7

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
a = [{'s1': 'INT', 's2': 'INT'}, 
     {'s1': 'TINYINT', 's2': 'TINYINT'}, 
     {'s1': 'SMALLINT', 's2': 'SMALLINT'}, 
     {'s1': 'BIGINT', 's2': 'BIGINT'}, 
     {'s1': 'BIT', 's2': 'VARCHAR(10)'}, 
     {'s1': 'FLOAT', 's2': 'FLOAT'}]

d = {x['s1']: x['s2'] for x in a}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'BIGINT': 'BIGINT',
 'BIT': 'VARCHAR(10)',
 'FLOAT': 'FLOAT',
 'INT': 'INT',
 'SMALLINT': 'SMALLINT',
 'TINYINT': 'TINYINT'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a *simple python code* and it gives the same output which is asked in the question.

```
dict_list = [{'s1': 'INT', 's2': 'INT'}, {'s1': 'TINYINT', 's2': 'TINYINT'}, {'s1': 'SMALLINT', 's2': 'SMALLINT'}, {'s1': 'BIGINT', 's2': 'BIGINT'}, {'s1': 'BIT', 's2': 'VARCHAR(10)'}, {'s1': 'FLOAT', 's2': 'FLOAT'}]
new_dict = {}
for dl in dict_list:
    new_dict[dl['s1']] = dl['s2']

print(new_dict)
```

**The below output we get by running this code snippet**

```
{'SMALLINT': 'SMALLINT', 'INT': 'INT', 'FLOAT': 'FLOAT', 'TINYINT': 'TINYINT', 'BIGINT': 'BIGINT', 'BIT': 'VARCHAR(10)'}
```

Answer (score -1):

*though* keyur Pordars answer will work out, but to make it more ***generic*** using dict comprehension using python 3.6.

```
b = {list(k.values())[0]:list(k.values())[1] for k in a} 

# k.values() return the **view** of the values (not a list in python 3) of

# each dict item in the list and then we wrap it into a list a and index it.

print(b) # print the output

# OUTPUT {'INT': 'INT', 'TINYINT': 'TINYINT', 'SMALLINT': 'SMALLINT', 'BIGINT': 'BIGINT', 'BIT': 'VARCHAR(10)', 'FLOAT': 'FLOAT'}
```

Comment: `values()` order isn't guaranteed. So Keyur answer is the only valid approach

Comment: check out Martijn Pieters♦ answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)