# Convert a list to dictionary without extra curly brackets being added

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a list like this:

```
alist = [{'key': 'value'}]
```

And then I convert it to a dictionary like this

```
adict = dict(alist)
```

The formatting becomes

```
{'{''key: 'value}'}
```

This makes it so I can't access the data from the dictionary.  Is there a way to convert the list to a dictionary without there being extra {' '} -- brackets and single quotes

Comment: The code you posted does not run without exceptions. It does not produce the output you posted. Please check again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Comment: `adict = alist[0]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index `0` to avoid the extra `{ }` braces because the dictionary can be accessed as `alist[0]`. Moreover, you do not need `dict` additionally because your list content is already a dictionary

```
adict = alist[0]
```

Now you get the desired behavior

```
print (adict)
# {'key': 'value'}
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: It works for me. Anyway, `dict` is not need here because the list contains already a dictionary. Check my edit

Answer (score 1):

If you first structure your list by swapping the curly braces, you won't have any issues using this :)

dict([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)])

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to initialise a dictionary object with a key value pair (or a bunch of key value pairs), why would you use a list first?

You could simple write

```
adict = {'key': 'value', 'Hello': 'world' }

print(adict)
```