# How to unpack or merge a variadic list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/5811400), in Python 3.5 or greater, it is possible to merge two dictionaries `x` and `y` by unpacking them:

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

Is it possible to unpack a variadic list of dictionaries?

Something like

```
def merge(*dicts):
    return {***dicts} # this fails, of course. What should I use here?
```

For instance, I would expect that

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]
{***list_of_dicts} == {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Note that this question is not about how to *merge* lists of dictionaries since the link above provides an answer to this. The question here is: is it possible, and how, to unpack lists of dictionaries?

As stated in the comments, this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict). However, unpacking a list of dictionaries is different from simply merging them. Supposing that there was an operator `***` designed to unpack lists of dictionaries, and given

```
def print_values(a, b, c, d):
    print('a =', a)
    print('b =', b)
    print('c =', c)
    print('d =', d)

list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]
```

it would be possible to write

```
print_values(***list_of_dicts)
```

instead of

```
print_values(**merge(list_of_dicts))
```

Comment: No, there is not a native way to do so with syntax sugar.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I think that your comment is the most exact answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: Related, maybe even a duplicate since the answer to this question is simply "No": [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3494906/7851470)

Comment: @Georgy, thanks for pointing that out. In fact, the solution `{k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}` seems really nice. I'm not sure, however, if this is a duplicate since I was looking for a syntax sugar for unpacking lists of dictionaries, while that question concerned merging.

Comment: @Georgy, I edited the question aiming to show another application of unpacking besides merging. Hopefully, it clarifies the distinction between my question and the one shared by you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution is using  `collections.ChainMap`

```
from collections import ChainMap

dict(ChainMap(*list_of_dicts[::-1]))

Out[88]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: ChainMap works even better than merging: it avoids creating a new dict. Also, it is possible to see ChainMap as a list of dicts (through ChainMap.maps) or as a merged dict (as you showed in your answer). Moreover, it provides more flexibility and uses a standard package instead of a self-implemented function. Very good, thank you!

Comment: Additionally, it supports both types of unpacking. Defining `cm = ChainMap(*list_of_dicts[::-1])`, one can use list unpacking, as in `*cm.maps`, and dict unpacking, as in `**cm`.

Comment: Came here to see why my answer had been unaccepted; this is much better. I don't think I ever noticed `ChainMap` before.

Answer (score 6):

There's no syntax for that, but you can use `itertools.chain` to concatenate the key/value tuples from each dict into a single stream that `dict` can consume.

```
from itertools import chain


def merge(*dicts):
    return dict(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in dicts))
```

You can also unpack a list created by a list comprehension as well:

```
def merge(*dicts):
    return dict(*[d.items() for d in dicts])
```

Comment: The second implementation of `merge` is the closest to what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could just iterate over the list and use `update`:

```
lst = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]

dct = {}
for item in lst:
    dct.update(item)

print(dct)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems very good for merging `dict`s. Actually, it is the answer provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/5811400). However, this focuses more on the merging instead of the use of unpacking, which was my first concern, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To merge multiple dictionaries you can use the function `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

lst = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]

reduce(lambda x, y: dict(**x, **y), lst)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: This one is indeed really nice. Just curious (this is not critical in my problem), regarding performance, is this implementation faster than the others?

Comment: @rugortal I don't think so. In this solution your build a new dictionary for each subdictionary and in another solution with `update` you have one dictionary and update it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and put this iterable object as an argument to dict

```
def merge(*dicts):
    lst = [*[d.items() for d in dicts]]
    return dict(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very close to what I was looking for. I'll stick to the selected answer for two reasons, though: it was posted before, and that version doesn't create the intermediate `lst`.

Comment: Can you post the whole code because I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list comprehension to iterate over all the dicts in the list and then iterate over each if those dicts' items and finally convert them to dict

```
>>> lst = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':2}]
>>> dict(kv for d in lst for kv in d.items())
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to merge two dicts at a time using `dict.update`

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> lst = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':1}, {'d':2}]
>>> reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.update(d2) or d1, lst, {})
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you *dicts its put in as a tuple, you can pull the list out with d[0], then use this comprehension for nonuniform keys

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}]

def merge(*dicts):    
    return dict( j for i in dicts[0] for j in i.items())

print(merge(list_of_dicts))
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
[Program finished]
```