# Merge two variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two variable a and b assigned some values in a list, merge those values as below

```
a = [{'test0': '-166.05043999999998'},
 {'test1': '0.39523979999999925'},
 {'test2': '0.8905380999999923'}]

b = [{'test3': '-168.05043999999998'},
 {'test4': '1.39523979999999925'},
 {'test5': '2.8905380999999923'}]
```

and I want to make it as

```
  ab = [{'test0': '-166.05043999999998',
 'test1': '0.39523979999999925',
 'test2': '0.8905380999999923',
 'test3': '-168.05043999999998',
 'test4': '1.39523979999999925',
 'test5': '2.8905380999999923'}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Comment: ```a += b``` seems the simplest answer

Answer (score 1):

Im not a expert in Python myself but this should work :)

```
a = [{'test0': '-166.05043999999998'},
 {'test1': '0.39523979999999925'},
 {'test2': '0.8905380999999923'}]

b = [{'test3': '-168.05043999999998'},
 {'test4': '1.39523979999999925'},
 {'test5': '2.8905380999999923'}]

ab = []

for i in a:
    ab.append(i)

for i in b:
    ab.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

python

```
a = [{'test0': '-166.05043999999998'},
     {'test1': '0.39523979999999925'},
     {'test2': '0.8905380999999923'}]
b = [{'test3': '-168.05043999999998'},
    {'test4': '1.39523979999999925'},
    {'test5': '2.8905380999999923'}]
a + b
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: My explanation is you can just add the variables you want to merge with