# Change List to Dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
list = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
```

i want to convert that list to dict like this:

```
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: please check it. it help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Comment: Those links already provided are helpful. And you also shouldn't use `list` and `dict` as variable names, otherwise your won't have access to those type names anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
result = {}

for elm in let:
    for i,value in elm.items():
        dictionary[i] = value

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested loop to flatten the list of dicts, then use the `dict` constructor.

```py
l = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
result = dict(i for d in l for i in d.items())
```

It's also possible to "merge" these dicts into one in place:

```py
l = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
result = l[0]
for d in l[1:]:
    result.update(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create empty dictionary and using for loop you can add key : value to dictionary.

```
lst = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
my_dict = {}

for ele in lst:
    for k,v in ele.items():
        my_dict[k] = v

print(my_dict) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```