# Python def vowelCount() counting the number of vowels

Tags: python

I have defined a vowel count() function which is to count the number of vowels in a user input returning count from the vowel count() function. My def structure doesn't work.

Addition: How not equal the user input into any number?

```
# Defining Function
def vowelCount(data):  # Counting the number of vowels in a word
    count = 0
    list1 = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    for input in data:
        if input in list1:
            count += 1
    return count
while redo == True:
  try:
    userinput = str(input("Enter String Data: "))
    if (userinput >= 0) or (userinput <= 0):  # userinput should not be equal to a number
        print("2Please enter an alphabetical value.")
        break
    except:
        print("!Please enter an alphabetical value.")
        exit()
    print("Number of Vowels: ", vowelCount(userinput))
```

Comment: There are a few bugs in your code.  To start, the `return` has the wrong indentation.

Comment: Your `return` statement is inside the loop, so you return after checking the first character. It should be indented one level less.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the problem of your indenting. `return` should be the same indent as `for`.
As for the number checking, you can simply use `userinput.isalpha()`. This checks if every element in the string is in the alphabet.

Comment: Thank for this Oplxy,, greatly helps.