# Using pandas' groupby and agg to merge column containing dicts

Tags: python, pandas

python 3.6.5

seasoned python veteran
new to pandas and dataframes

given

```
d = {'time':['2021-08-12 14:59:15.230','2021-08-12 14:59:15.230','2021-08-12 14:59:15.230']
   , 'dayy':['14:59:15.231818','14:59:15.231330','14:59:15.232206']
   , 'catg':['40B0','4035','40E8']
   , 'data':[{'OQWOWF': '0', 'OQD8S1F': '10010100'},{'OQTADT': 30.0, 'OQTAVL': '0', 'OQAOAD': 2},{'OQGS01': '0', 'OQGS02': '0', 'OQGS03': '0'}]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame( data=d)
print(df)
```

yields

```
                      time             dayy  catg                                           data
0  2021-08-12 14:59:15.230  14:59:15.231818  40B0         {'OQWOWF': '0', 'OQD8S1F': '10010100'}
1  2021-08-12 14:59:15.230  14:59:15.231330  4035   {'OQTADT': 30.0, 'OQTAVL': '0', 'OQAOAD': 2}
2  2021-08-12 14:59:15.230  14:59:15.232206  40E8  {'OQGS01': '0', 'OQGS02': '0', 'OQGS03': '0'
```

how can I merge the dicts into one dict grouped by time?  ie

```
2021-08-12 14:59:15.230  {'OQWOWF': '0', 'OQD8S1F': '10010100', 'OQTADT': 30.0, 'OQTAVL': '0', 'OQAOAD': 2, 'OQGS01': '0', 'OQGS02': '0', 'OQGS03': '0'}
```

I've gotten the groupby and columns-listed parts down but sense I need either an .apply() or an .agg() function

```
df.groupby('time')['data'].???
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Still-learning Steve

Comment: related: [`df.groupby("time")['data'].agg(lambda x: {k: v for d in x for k, v in d.items()})`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom function to merge the dictionaries then use the function as `aggregate` for `groupby` object:

```py
def mergeDicts(series):
    result = {}
    for d in series.values:
        result.update(d)
    return result

df.groupby('time')['data'].agg(mergeDicts)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
time
2021-08-12 14:59:15.230    {'OQWOWF': '0', 'OQD8S1F': '10010100', 'OQTADT...
Name: data, dtype: object
```

**PS:** If multiple values exist for the same dictionary key under a group, the resulting dictionary for the group will always have the last value.

Comment: both solutions work - I went with the one-liner.  Thanks so much!