# Merge "n" number json in for loop using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to merge "n" number of json files but i need to first load json from filepath and then use it. I referred below link but they already have json data available but in my case i want to first load json data in loop and then merge it. I am looking for generic way of doing it.

[How do I merge a list of dicts into a single dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494906/how-do-i-merge-a-list-of-dicts-into-a-single-dict)

My code: I want to first load json data for all the files and then merge it. I am trying something like below but it does not work and give `error as TypeError: str , bytes or ospath.like object, not Tuple`

```
def merge_JsonFiles(*file):
   result = {}
   for f in file:
     json_data = loadjson(file)
     result = {**json_data}
   return result

   merge_JsonFiles(file1, file2, file3)

def loadjson(file)
     with open(file , 'r') as fh:
       return json.load(fh)

Merge logic for two files = {**file1, **file2)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using below code

```
def merge_JsonFiles(*file):
   result = {}
   for f in file:       
     result = {**result, **loadjson(f)}
   return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

def loadjson(file):
    with open(file , 'r') as fh:
        return json.load(fh)

def merge_JsonFiles(*files):
    result = {}
    for f in files:
        json_data = loadjson(f)
        result = {**result, **json_data}
    return result

merge_JsonFiles('file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json')
```

In this code, `merge_JsonFiles` function takes an arbitrary number of file paths as arguments. It then loads each JSON file one by one using the loadjson function and merges them into one dictionary. Finally, the merged dictionary is returned.